# Im trying to run a pi-hole docker container and get the error message "no matching manifest for linux/mipsle in the manifest list entries"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-daemon, pihole

Update: It turns out it can't install pi-hole due to it not officially supporting the CPU architecture ("mips"). It has however been performed by https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/fnhfb8/pihole_for_mips_ci20/ that guy, but I'm not sure how to modify the yml file to retrieve his code instead of the official pi-hole code. Everything needed should be in this post, hopefully.

I'm trying to run docker pi-hole and after configuring the .yml file, creating folders for the volumes, and creating fixed routes, I get the error message: "no matching manifest for linux/mipsle in the manifest list entries" when trying to run the container. I'll include all the commands I used in case I typed anything strange.

Any help with decoding and solving this error message will be greatly appreciated.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

# More info at https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/ and https://docs.pi-hole.net/
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:2021.09
    hostname: pihole
    environment:
      TZ: SE
      # WEBPASSWORD: 'set a secure password here or it will be random'
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      - './pihole/etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
      - './pihole/etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
      - './pihole/var-log/:/var/log'
      - './pihole/etc-cont-init.d/10-fixroutes.sh:/etc/cont-init.d/10-fixroutes.sh'
    # Recommended but not required (DHCP needs NET_ADMIN)
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      internal:
      lan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.3

networks:
  internal:
  lan:
    name: lan
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: br-lan.20
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

making volumes

```
mkdir -p ./pihole/etc-pihole/
mkdir -p ./pihole/etc-dnsmasq.d/
mkdir -p ./pihole/var-log/
mkdir -p ./pihole/var-log/lighttpd
chown 33:33 ./pihole/var-log/lighttpd
mkdir -p ./pihole/etc-cont-init.d/
```

setting routes

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/with-contenv bash
set -e

echo "fixing routes"
ip route del default
ip route add default via 172.18.0.1
echo "done fixing routes"' >> ./pihole/etc-cont-init.d/10-fixroutes.sh
chmod 755 ./pihole/etc-cont-init.d/10-fixroutes.sh
```

running the container

```
cd ~
docker-compose up -d pihole
```

Comment: Do you mind providing the output of `uname -m`, so that we know what architecture you're on?

Comment: @NickODell "uname -m" gave me "mips", not certain if this was what you were looking for

Comment: Yes, it was. Looking on the [docker hub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole/tags) website, I don't see any images compiled for the mips architecture.

Comment: @NickODell so it wont work on this device?

Comment: Probably not. One person on reddit had luck compiling their own version, though. https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/fnhfb8/pihole_for_mips_ci20/

Comment: but wait, is it pi-hole or docker thats being the issue? i thought docker was messing this up

Comment: Docker wants to download an image which matches your current architecture. Since pi-hole doesn't publish images with your architecture, you get an error.

Comment: ah that makes sense, how would i modify the .yml file to to ask for the version he posted on reddit, any link to the github in the yml comment seem to be commented out (i didnt write that code and it was taken from a guide)